# Converting image *.rgb -> *.tif / *.tiff

Tags: image, rgb, tiff

I need to convert a image (*.rgb) to a *.tiff image.

I cannot view the image (web says, *.rgb is readable with xnview or GIMP -> does not work in this case) :/

xnConvert does not work either

just to rename, too...

Comment: In what *file format* is your `.rgb` files? SGI Image File? It's probably not that hard to convert, but you might have to really know your tools, or even write some code yourself to do it. As it stands, I believe your question doesn't really fit SO.

Comment: Open source QGIS helped :)